# ValueError: Setting void-array with object members using buffer. Plotting a timeseries of an numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, strptime, genfromtxt

I have 2 numpy arrays with (time and date), and the third with rain. At the end I would like to plot all the info at a xy-plot with matplotlib!
This i what I got so far

```
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


date = np.array(["01.06.2015", "01.06.2015", "01.06.2015"], dtype=object)
time = np.array(["12:23:00", "14:54:00", "14:56:00"], dtype=object)
# Rain
rain = np.array([2.544, 1.072, 1.735]

# Calculations to make one array of time and date,
# called timestamp
A = np.vstack((date, time))
A_transp = A.transpose()
A_transp.shape
A_transp.type
```

So at the end as mentioned I would like to have an (x,y)-Plot, with timestamps(so time and date combined as an array of floating point numbers and the rain on the other axes.

Thank you for your help

### Markus

Thank you for your help, but I do not come to a conclusion!
Further stepps I did!

```
# Get a new .out file, to get a time tuple
# see strptime. 
# Finally I would like to make a floating point number out of the 
# timetuple, to plot the hole thing! 
#
mydata = np.savetxt('A_transp.out', A_transp
       ,fmt="%s")
# Dateconv
dateconv = lambda s: datetime.strptime(s, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
# ColNames
col_names = ["Timestamp"]
# DataTypes
dtypes = ["object"]
# Read in the new file
mydata_next = np.genfromtxt('A_transp.out', delimiter=None,
     names=col_names, dtype=dtypes, converters={"Timestamp":dateconv})
```

So after the np.genfromtxt following error message appears

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "parsivel.py", line 155, in <module>
names=col_names, dtype=dtypes, converters={"Timestamp":dateconv})
File "/home/unix/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1867, in genfromtxt
output = np.array(data, dtype)
ValueError: Setting void-array with object members using buffer.
```

What I would try after that would be the following.

```
#B = mdates.strpdate2num(mydata_next)   # fail
#B = time.mktime(mydata_next)           # fail
#B = plt.dates.date2num(mydata_next)    # fail
```

And finally I would like to plot the following

```
# Plot
# Fail
#plt.plot_date(mydata_next, rain)
#plt.show()
```

But at the moment all the plots fail, because I can not make a time tuple out of A_transp! Maybe also the strptime function is not right here, or there is another way as the detour via np.savetxt and the try of rearanging A_transp?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for plot? http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot

Comment: Please take your time and read the documentation and eventual tutorials. If and when you encounter a problem you can post it here and we will try to help you.

Comment: @code11 Thank you for your help, but I do not come to a conclusion! Further stepps I did are in the edited version! Thxs

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your original date and time arrays, you can obtain a date-time string representation in a single array just by adding them:

```
In[61]: date_time = date + time

In[62]: date_time
Out[62]: array(['01.06.201512:23:00', '01.06.201514:54:00', '01.06.201514:56:00'], dtype=object)
```

Now you can convert the date-time strings into datetime format. For example:

```
In[63]: date_time2 = [datetime.strptime(d, '%d.%m.%Y%H:%M:%S') for d in date_time]

In[64]: date_time2
Out[64]: 
[datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 1, 12, 23),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 1, 14, 54),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 1, 14, 56)]
```

And that's all you need to plot your data with:

```
plt.plot_date(date_time2, rain)
```